# How to access array inside JQuery Succes/Done function in IE?

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer

I have a function where I work through an array to go get distances for our locations. Upon return from that call I want to update the original Array with this new distance value. It is working in all browsers except IE (testing on IE11). It appears that the array is considered undefined.

> Error: Unable to set property 'LocationDistance' of undefined or null reference

`LocationsArr` does exist, and I can pull/see values from it in the outer function, but not within the `success:` function of the `$.ajax` call.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

```
function getLocationDistance() {
  let origin = UserLatitude + "," + UserLongitude
  let l = 0
  let distance = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < LocationsArr.length; i++) {
    let data = {
      ak: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
      origin: origin,
      ID: LocationsArr[i].LocationID,
      destination: LocationsArr[i].LocationDestination
    };
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "https://www.kaleidahealth.org/GoogleAPIServices/DistanceMatrix.svc/GetTripInfo",
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(result) {
        distance = result.distance.replace(" miles", "")

        // IE CAN'T SEE LocationsArr ARRAY - ALL OTHER BROWSERS CAN
        LocationsArr[i].LocationDistance = distance;

        l++;
        if (l === i) {
          buildLocationList();
        }
      },
      error: function(err) {
        alert("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(err))
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is with `i`, not `locationsArr`. It sounds like IE11 doesn't properly implement `let` bindings in `for` loops.

Comment: I agree. It has to do with i. Ironically, I converted all my instances let to var and now it doesn't work in any browser.

Comment: I switched the for loop to $.each(LocationsArr, function(i) {} and all is well now. Thanks for the suggestion!